# How to override a @define in the scaladocs of a subclass

Tags: scala, scaladoc

I found [docs for the `@define` scaladoc macro](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scaladoc/for-library-authors.html#macros) but they don't go into any depth.

What I'm trying to do is write documentation in a base class/trait in a generic way, with `@define`d variables so that the wording in the generated docs for the subclasses makes sense.

I've distilled this down to an example of something I would have expected to work, but doesn't:

```
/**
  * @define Word base-word
  */
class DocTestBase {

    /** Does a $Word
      *
      * @return
      */
    def foo = 1
}

/**
  * @define Word subclass word!
  */
class DocTestSubclass extends DocTestBase
```

With the above, I'd expect the generated documentation for `DocTestSubclass#foo` to say "Does a subclass word!", but as you can see below, it doesn't.

[image]

FWIW I also tried this on Scala 2.12 but the result is the same.

How do I get this to work as I expect? Is this a bug in scaladoc?

Comment: Looks like it's still an opened issue: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9785